# How to capture ActionResult Api Response in Angular?

Tags: c#, angular

I have the below method in my user controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Create(User user)
{
    var userCreated = userService.register(user); // returns true or false

    if (userCreated)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Could not create user.");
    }
}
```

This method should then be captured in my angular calling the service:

```js
onSubmit(user: User): void {
    this.userService.registerUser(user).subscribe((response) => {
        console.warn(response);
    });
}
```

The register URL method:

```js
registerUser(user: User): Observable <boolean> {
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return this.http.post<boolean>(environment.userUrl, user, httpOptions);
}
```

Unfortunately, the console writes null. Am I missing out anything? I want to capture whether the status is `OK` or `BadRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you are missing to return the value of your response:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Create(User user)
{
    var userCreated = userService.register(user); // returns true or false

    if (userCreated)
    {
        return Ok(userCreated); // <= HERE
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Could not create user.");
    }
}
```

After changing the above, you should be OK.

A small tip is that you don't need to add `HttpOptions` on every request in Angular.
The `HttpClient` is doing that for you:

```
registerUser(user: User): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.post<boolean>(environment.userUrl, user);
}
```

PS: `Ok()` in C# means that you are returning a response with code 200.
On the other hand, a `BadRequest()` will result a 400 error code and will be caught as error inside subscription. In your case I thing that the code in the back end should be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Create(User user)
{
    var userCreated = userService.register(user); // returns true or false
    return Ok(userCreated);
}
```

Comment: Probably he wants to return created user back to the client, not the flag.
Also `BadRequest()` results into `400` not `500`.

Comment: Thank you about `BadResult`, you are right. Whatever he wants to return, must be inside `OK()` :)

Comment: @StPaulis Thank you very much. This helps.